# Why does "appAuthRedirectScheme" as manifest placeholder has no effect?

Tags: android, flutter, redirect, oauth

I'm trying to build a simple single sign-on example with flutter. Therefore I need to redirect the user after authenticating at the identity provider back to my app. I use the Flutter AppAuth Plugin to do so. But even when I follow the "Getting Started" section, it does not work.
I've added

```
manifestPlaceholders = [
  'appAuthRedirectScheme': 'my.example.redirect'
]
```

to my grade file, but the *open by default* page of the app doesn't show anything:

[image]

And when I enter a URL like "my.example.redirect/test" to chrome, it doesn't open the app.

So does anyone have an idea, what I made wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, you using return url wrong, send something like "my.example.redirect:/callback"
because scheme is before path,  like scheme http, or https.

hopefully it will help.

Comment: Did this answer fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

`my.example.redirect` is a custom scheme in your case.

In *App Info > Opening Links* only [Android App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html) with http/https  schemes are displayed.

You can try running the following and see if your app opens:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d my.example.redirect
```

This would work because, by setting `appAuthRedirectScheme`, appAuth automatically registered the intent-filter for `net.openid.appauth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity`.

You can also register `/test` in your AndroidManifest.xml yourself like this:

```
        <activity
            android:name="net.openid.appauth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data
                    android:scheme="my.example.redirect"
                    android:pathPattern="/test"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

If you want to see the App Links under App Info use the following instead:

```
<data android:scheme="https" android:host="my.example.redirect" android:pathPattern="/redirect"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, I don't believe you are supposed to have any quotes around the key **appAuthRedirectScheme**.